# Cannot capture photo via camera in android 4.0.3 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, mobile-application, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm new to android development. I'm developing an application for android 4.0.3 devices, in my app I capture an image using camera.

When I test in the emulator (android 4.0.3), clicking the capture button displays the following message `your sd card is full`. So please help me to solve the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a real device to capture image.

Comment: First i need to check with emulator then i deploy in real device.I had one in emulator capturing photo is working or not working?

Comment: your comment is quite confusing.